# Method 'Add' of object "workbooks" failed - Importing excel workbook with vba Access 2007

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

RESOLVED: I've accepted an answer below from Siddharth. I greatly appreciate everyone's help and I am amazed at the swift responses. I always learn something new when coming to this community for help, you guys are awesome.

---

Thanks for taking a moment to look at my message. I've put together a script (thanks in no small part to the great help here on SO) that takes an excel workbook and imports each worksheet to a separate table in an Access 2007 database. The script used to work fine on my PC but since a recent recovery from a hardware failure I haven't been able to get the script to run. To top it off, my client is getting different error messages than my own.

A large part of the issue has to do with my object references, when I have the Microsoft Excel 14 Object Library added as a reference from the tools menu, all works fine. However, the client has a different version of Office on their systems and wishes this app to be distributed to others who *may* have other versions of office installed. I've tried to implement some form of late binding, but I may not be approaching this correctly. Code is below:

edit: current code updated again, related to the accepted post from Siddharth below

```
Private Sub Command101_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_Command101_Click

    ' Set up excel object
    Dim excelApp As Object
    Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    ' Set up workbook object
    Dim excelbook As Object

    ' Set up file selection objects with parameters
    Dim fileSelection As Object
    Dim intNoOfSheets As Integer, intCounter As Integer
    Dim strFilePath As String, strLastDataColumn As String
    Dim strLastDataRow As String, strLastDataCell As String

    ' Prompt user with file open dialog
    Set fileSelection = Application.FileDialog(1)
    fileSelection.AllowMultiSelect = False
    fileSelection.Show

    ' Get the selected file path
    strFilePath = fileSelection.SelectedItems.Item(1)
    ' Open the workbook using the file path
    Set excelbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(strFilePath)
    ' Get the number of worksheets
    intNoOfSheets = excelbook.Worksheets.Count
    ' Set up object for current sheet name
    Dim CurrSheetName As String
    ' Disable errors
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    ' Loop through each sheet, adding data to the named table that matches the sheet
    For intCounter = 1 To intNoOfSheets
        excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).Activate

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
        excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).Name, strFilePath, True, _
        excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).Name & "!" & _
        Replace(excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).UsedRange.Address, "$", "")
    Next

    ' Close Excel objects
    excelbook.Close
    excelApp.Quit
    Set excelApp = Nothing
    ' Confirmation message
    MsgBox "Data import Complete!", vbOKOnly, ""
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Err_Command101_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

The failure seems to occur for the client on the line `Set excelbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add` with this message:

[image: "Method 'Add' of object 'Workbooks' failed"]

My question is somewhat twofold:
a) Have I implemented late binding properly? and
b) How can I resolve this error while making sure to keep the script independent of a specific Office release?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Nothing wrong with that line. Can you remove `On Error GoTo Err_Command101_Click` for the time being and add this `excelApp.Visible = True` after `Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` Now debug each line. Which line gives you the error?

Comment: On my own machine:
File open prompt opens, and I select a file. I get the error "Run-time error '424: Object required". Unfortunately the client is remote so I can not test on their machine.

Comment: FWIW, I tried compiling your code and it choked on the `ActiveSheet` reference in the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` statement: "Compile error: Variable not defined.".

Comment: I agree with @GordThompson: I successfully reached the `For Loop` on testing.

Comment: `I get the error "Run-time error '424: Object required"` Which line?

Comment: Looks like the four lines including DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet... down to Replace(excelbook....)

Comment: Ah.. i think I know why... one moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the error is in this line

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, ActiveSheet.Name, _
    strFilePath, True, _
    excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).Name & "!" & _
    Replace(excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).UsedRange.Address, "$", "")
```

`ActiveSheet.Name` <+++++ This is causing the error.

Change that to `excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).Name`

In Latebinding the code will not understand what `Activesheet` is

**FOLLOWUP**

You are getting a compile error because you did not add " _" at the end of the first line in `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`

Copy the below code and paste it as it is in your code.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).Name, _
strFilePath, True, _
excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).Name & "!" & _
Replace(excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).UsedRange.Address, "$", "")
```

Comment: That edit appears to produce a syntax error when changing ActiveSheet.Name -> excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).Name

Comment: Ok debug that line and except the MSACCESS Constants, check what is the value of the rest of the variable. For example `excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).Name` and `strFilePath` and `excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).Name & "!" & _
    Replace(excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).UsedRange.Address, "$", "")`

Comment: In `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`, replace `ActiveSheet.Name` with `excelApp.ActiveSheet.Name`.  (`ActiveSheet` is a property of the Excel application object.  That change allows the code to compile without error from my Access 2007 with no Excel reference set.)

Comment: @HansUp: yes that will also work but since Miguet is using this line `excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter).Activate` that means `excelbook.Worksheets(intCounter)` is the activesheet.

Comment: Aha, I was just trying to make the code compile.  I'll leave you to keep up your good work here.  :-)

Comment: Seems I'm stuck on on a compile error, won't let me do anything else. I should mention I'm somewhat new to vba and am not entirely sure of how to check variable values.

Comment: Did you add `, _` after the first line in `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` ?

Comment: edit: Apologies! I didn't add the _ character, works for the moment. Now I need to send it to the client for testing on their system. Thanks!

Comment: refresh the page. Copy the code as it is from the `FOLLOWUP`. Now test it?

Answer (score 3):

The `Workbooks.Add` method creates a new workbook.  I don't understand why you're using that.  Seems so me you want the user to select an existing workbook and open that, so you should use `Workbooks.Open` instead.

As to whether you have implemented late binding correctly, make sure your code module includes `Option Explicit` in its Declarations section (see Gord's answer for useful details), and then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  That effort will alert you to anything in your code (objects, properties, methods, constants) for which you need further work to make them compatible with late binding.

This is a big red flag:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
```

Turning `SetWarnings` off can suppress error information which you need to help understand why your code isn't doing what you want.  If you feel you must turn off `SetWarnings` in your production code, at least leave it on during development and debugging.

Comment: I've commented out that line and have taken Siddharth's suggestion to add excelApp.Visible = True. With this the file does open and show up, but I still get an "object required" run time error.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I'll disable the warnings False for now.

Comment: + 1 BTW good catch - regarding it's futile to use `Workbooks.Add`

Answer (score 2):

I'll add this just for reference... In the VBA IDE Window choose `Tools > Options...` and ensure that the "Require Variable Declaration" box has a check mark in it:

[image: vbaOptions]

Then, check all of your existing modules to make sure that the very first two lines are

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
```

The `Option Explicit` statement will be added to any new Modules that you create, but you'll need to add it yourself for any existing Modules.

Comment: @MiguetSchwab `Option Explicit` tells the compiler to only accept variable references that have been explicitly declared (e.g., in a `Dim` statement). Without that option the compiler will "miss" typos and just assume that `item` and `iten` are two different variables, even though your code has `Dim item As whatever` but `iten` has never been declared.